# library integration limit in IOS / Apple

Tags: ios

I haeard from some android developer that there is a library limit in android provided by google so:

**Is there such scenarios exist in apple or how any library integration limit in a single app ios/apple. ??**

**How many libraries can we integrate in single project?**

Comment: A library limit in Android? Are you sure he meant it as an actual number of libraries you can integrate into an app before the build crashes? Never heard of such a thing

Answer (score 0):

I think the think you heard about is [MultiDex](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html) on Android which is related with total count of functions inside app including 3rd party libraries.

> As the Android platform has continued to grow, so has the size of Android apps. When your app and the libraries it references reach a certain size, you encounter build errors that indicate your app has reached a limit of the Android app build architecture.

But as far as I know there is nothing like MultiDex on iOS.

Answer (score 0):

There is no actual numeric limit, but adding an embedded dynamic library will add to your launch time. There is a requirement for an app to launch within 20 seconds.

Here is a github discussion from 2015 of the problem with many dylibs and slow launch times:
https://github.com/artsy/eigen/issues/586

Apple did a WWDC 16 session about launch times and said the following:
https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/406/

> If you take longer than 20 seconds, the OS will kill your app, assuming it's going through an infinite loop, and we've all had that experience.

...

> So dylib loading, the big thing to understand about dylib loading and the slowdown that you'll see from it, is that embedded dylibs can be expensive.
>
> So Nick said an average app can be 100 to 400 dylibs. But OS dylibs are fast because when we build the OS, we have ways of pre-calculating a lot of that data.

...

> So you absolutely can and should use some [dylibs], but it's good to try to target a limited number, we would, I would say off hand, a good target's about a half a dozen.